# Oracle-like sequence in Linux?

Tags: linux

I need to tag parallel calls to my program with a unique number in single common log file (thousands of calls in a day).

For this an Oracle sequence would be perfect (returned number guaranteed uniqueness). I could implement this with a small C program (C for speed, this is the issue here) using system file locking facilities, but does Linux provide such a facility already (/dev/increment_forever would be nice :)), or did somebody out there already make such a utility ?

Edit: forgot to mention that my program is not a persistent process (it's not a server), so 100 calls == 100 instances of my program. Using an FS file to store a counter would be too slow with needed locking mechanism.. that's why something like /dev/increment_forever (alias: system facility) would be perfect..

Comment: Maybe you could use shared memory and [GCC atomic primitives](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) or [C++ equivalents](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic).

Comment: you might check out some of netflix's work, hystrix springs to mind, they also had a low level HPV hook thing.  Hystrix: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Metrics-and-Monitoring

Comment: I seriously doubt that using `flock` would be too slow. You forget how expensive starting up a process (fork and exec) is; next to those costs (which you've already indicated you're willing to pay), the relative costs of advisory locking are trivial.

Comment: That said -- if all you need is a "unique number", you don't need any kind of locking or synchronization for that at all; a type 1 UUID will suit the purpose.

Comment: Also, persistence needs (if any) should be covered here. What happens (needs to happen) on reboot?

Answer (score 1):

First: You're seriously overestimating the costs of advisory locking on Linux. Compared to the price you're already paying for a unique instance of your program to start up, using `flock` to get an exclusive lock before updating a file with a unique identifier is cheap. (Doing atomic rename-based updates -- of a file other than the one the lock is held on, of course -- has some extra cost around filesystem metadata churn and journaling, but for thousands of calls per day this is nothing; one would worry if you needed to generate thousands of identifiers per second).

Second: Your question implies that what you actually need is uniqueness, as opposed to ordering. This puts you in a space where you don't necessarily need coordination or locking at all. Consider the approach taken by type-1 UUIDs (using a very high-precision timestamp, potentially in combination with other information -- consider CPU identifier, as only one process can be on a single CPU at a given time; or PID, as only one process can have a PID at a given time), or that taken by type-4 UUIDs (using a purely random value). Combine your process's PID and the timestamp at which it started (the latter is column 22 of `/proc/self/stat`), and you should be set.

---

This is much slower than a native C implementation using the flock call directly, but should give you an idea of a correct implementation:

```
retrieve_and_increment() {
  local lock_fd curr_value next_value

  # using a separate lockfile to allow atomic replacement of content file
  exec {lock_fd}<>counter.lock
  flock -x "$lock_fd" || {
    exec {lock_fd}<&-
    return 1
  }
  next_value=$(( $(<counter) + 1 ))
  printf '%s\n' "$next_value" >counter.next && mv counter.next counter
  exec {lock_fd}<&- # close our handle on the lock

  # then, when not holding the lock, write result to stdout
  # ...that way we decrease the time spent holding the lock if stdout blocks
  printf '%s\n' "$next_value"
}
```

Note that we're spinning up an external command for `mv`, so `flock` isn't the only time we're paying fork/exec costs here -- a reason why this would be better implemented within your C program.

---

For other people reading this who genuinely need thousands of unique sequence values generated per second, I would strongly suggest using a [Redis](http://redis.io/) database for this purpose. [The `INCR` command](http://redis.io/commands/incr) will atomically increment the value associated with a key in O(1) time and return that value. If setting up a TCP connection to a local service is considered too slow/expensive, Redis also supports connections via Unix sockets.

On my not-particularly-beefy laptop:

```
$ redis-benchmark -t INCR -n 100000 -q
INCR: 95510.98 requests per second
```

95,000 requests per second is probably quite sufficient. :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I need thousands per day, not per second. I'll try flock (shell command) on Monday and see what cost it exactly carries when 10k calls are simulated (as fast as the system can create processes - a RedHat 6 VM). I was thinking uniqueness+increment so as to number calls in log files (chronologically) - useful to production guys - before my client pulled the thousand calls rabbit out of his hat on Friday :) The ID is to prefix all matching call log messages (so as be able to "grep" a single call for trace), a UUID is too big and ugly when sth like "0417" could do.